# Payment security on Android App

Tags: authentication, mobile, pci-dss, web-service, asp.net

I am developing an application from which users browse and buy books. The client can be Android ,iOS, Mac. The server is ASP.net Web APIs.

I know there are many payment services available. One of these is Authorize.net, which I think I will use. When a user pays for a book, he/she will get a unique link to download data from the server. I want to prevent other users who has unlawfully retrieved that link from downloading data. Additionally, I want to keep users' payment information secure.

I have no experience in security. So, please give some advice on how to implement this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hacking is creativity. Applications are complex and when an attacker can look at the entire application he can see interesting ways of abusing it.  In the light of a few sentences explaining some vague application I would consider the following:

1)[The OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main)

2)Make sure you verify the SSL certificate when connecting to the APIs you need.

3)Avoid cryptography whenever possible.  It can cause a lot of problems especially if you are not a dedicated cryptographer.

4)You cannot control the client,  avoid  [CWE-602 violations](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html).

Comment: I assume that you mean by "avoid cryptography", avoid *building* it, not using it, correct? I would also add relevance of PCI:DSS requirements...

Comment: @AviD considering he just used SSL I can only assume that is what he meant.

Comment: @AviD♦ well it should be avoided in favor of another system if possible. Often cryptography is the only tool that can be used,  and that is perfect place for it.